# TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for i in range(len(results)):
    lexer = shlex.shlex(results[i]['values'])
    lexer.commenters = False
    lexer.whitespace_split = True
    lexer.whitespace = ';'
    print(lexer)
    for pair in lexer:
        props = dict(pair.split("=", 1))
```

I'm getting error in line 7. How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you show a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Side note: instead of iterating over the indices of a ``list`` to then get the elements via indexing, you can directly iterate over the elements. E.g. ``for result in results: lexer = shlex.shlex(result['values'])``.

Answer (score -1):

This is basically because you have converted the results variable to a bool using bool(results) or u have mistakenly made it and boolean value so its obviously true or false ... as you can not iterate through boolean values such as true or false you need a int or a string of char or a list to iterate through it... if ur using a list check whether if u have false or true in it

Comment: i have "values" column. In values column , there is two type of records. One is 'Data' and second one is 'IsCompressed'. i have to split 'values' into two new columns as 'Data' & 'IsCompressed'.



u'values': u'Data={"BotBuilder.Data.SessionState":{"callstack":[{"id":"*:Experience","state":{"BotBuilder.Data.WaterfallStep":0}}],"lastAccess":1538138334991,"version":0}};IsCompressed=False;'